# GLTF Embedded missing in V4

Tags: interface

In Blender 3 there were three GLTF export options:

- GLTF Binary (.glb)
- GLTF Seperate (.gltf + bin + textures)
- GLTF Embedded (.gltf)

We have a number of projects that use the "GLTF Embedded (.gltf)" format, but it's missing in Blender version 4.0.2.

Does anyone know why it was removed, and if it is going to be reintroduced?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/2148

Comment: Thank you.  Most helpful.